# I want to call Socket.current in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am working on a messaging app, and in the messaging app, I have created the socket in `messenger.js` as

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const Messages = () => {
const socket = useRef()

useEffect(
    () => {
      socket.current = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API)
}, [])
```

I have another file `test.js`

How can I pass socket to the test.js file without passing it a props. Since I am not using test.js in the `messenger.js`

Comment: Why not create the socket ref in the parent of both of them, then forward it to both components?

Comment: "*I am not using test.js in the messenger.js*" - then where *are* you using it? What guarantees that there is one `<Messages>` per test?

Answer (score 0):

Create new file SocketProvider.js to share your socket state with children components

```
import * as React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const SocketContext = React.createContext({});

export const useSocket = () => {
    return React.useContext(SocketContext).socket
};

const SocketProvider = ({token, children}) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = React.useState();

    const zoneManager = new ZonesManager();
    const activeRideManager = new ActiveRideManager();
    let newSocket;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (token) {

            const params = {token};
            const options = {query: params, transports: ['websocket']};
            newSocket = io(`http://yourSocketUrl`, options);

            //GLOBAL SOCKET EVENTS
            newSocket.on(SGE.CONNECT_EVENT, onConnect);
            newSocket.on(SGE.RECONNECT_EVENT, onReconnect);
            newSocket.on(SGE.DISCONNECT_EVENT, onDisconnect);
            newSocket.on(SGE.ERROR_EVENT, onError);

            // SOCKET APP GLOBAL STATE
            setSocket(newSocket);
        }
    }, [token]);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider
            value={socket}>{children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default SocketProvider;
```

Your App.js

```
 
import * as React from 'react';
import SocketProvider from "./src/context/SocketProvider";

const App = () => {
    return (
    // All component are inside this socket provider can access to socket state
        <SocketProvider token={token}>

            <AppContainer>
            </AppContainer>
        </SocketProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

How to use your socket state

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {useSocket} from "../context/SocketProvider";

const AppContainer = () => {

    // now you have access to socket.io
    const socket = useSocket();

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>AppContainer</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: Use `value={socket}` instead of `value={{socket}}`